# Docker pull public image repository not found

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am trying to do something very simple with Docker.

Pull this image here: https://hub.docker.com/r/nbcuniversalpaint/drupal

I tried the same thing with microsoft/aci-helloworld and it works fine.

With nbcuniversalpaint/drupal however I get this:

[image: error 1043 out of pulling from repository]

What is going wrong there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

docker tries to pull the `latest` tag by default, but the image your looking for doesn't contain this tag.
Try `docker pull nbcuniversalpaint/drupal:nginx` for example, or any of the other tags detailed here - https://hub.docker.com/r/nbcuniversalpaint/drupal/tags/